# Can't bind to 'fileUpload' since it isn't a known property of 'app-details-upload'

Tags: angular

I'm connecting my angular project with the AWS S3 bucket that I created. Also I'm follwing this tutorial https://grokonez.com/aws/angular-4-amazon-s3-example-get-list-files-from-s3-bucket. The error is in step 2.7.
When I´m trying to get the files using the [fileUpload] property I'm getting an error

Can't bind to 'fileUpload' since it isn't a known property of 'app-details-upload'.

1. If 'app-details-upload' is an Angular component and it has 'fileUpload' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-details-upload' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

Here is the piece of code that is giving the error

```
<div [hidden]="!showFile">
 <div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">List of Files</div>
  <div *ngFor="let file of fileUploads | async">
    <div class="panel-body">
     <app-details-upload [fileUpload]='file'></app-details-upload>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Module based routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the piece of code you have provided that is giving the error rather the component is not not declared.

Take it like a simple variable, example, lets say `myFunction.myProperty()`. Now without 1st declaring what `myFunction` represents then the code will not work.

In `Angular` before you can use a component you have to declare the component. To declare a component you need to add the component to the `declarations` array in the `NgModule`

In your **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [DetailsUploadComponent, ...]
})
```